# How can i upload images without waiting user to upload images Laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload, queue, background-process

I need to upload images to server, but it's take more time, therefore user wait for it to complete, if refreshing the webpage while upload Imges, image uploadImg wil fail.

But in facebook , twitter has no that kind of issue, they are upload images as background process.

How can i apply above senario in laravel?

Anyone know please help

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image with ajax request. if you do ajax request it will not load the page to save image.

```
    form method="post" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

in your form tag use **id="upload_form"**
and add this script end of your view file.
just pass your route in url.

```
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
     $('#upload_form').on('submit', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
       url:"{{ route('ajaxupload.action') }}",
       method:"POST",
       data:new FormData(this),
       dataType:'JSON',
       contentType: false,
       cache: false,
       processData: false,
       success:function(data)
       {
         console.log("data.message")
       }
      })
     });
    
    });
```

In the controller, you can be send back response with success and failure message

```
    return response()->json([
           'message'   => 'Image Upload Successfully'
          ]);
```

Visit https://www.webslesson.info/2018/09/upload-image-in-laravel-using-ajax.html for more clarifications